# ¿Se puede recibir una N cantidad de parámetros en una función?

Tags: sql, postgresql, funciones

Mi duda es la siguiente:

se puede recibir una N cantidad de parámetros en una función? en este caso números para luego retornar el promedio?

En otras palabras ingresar N cantidad de números al momento de llamar la función.

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para pasar un número arbitrario de argumentos a una función se debe pasar mediante un *array*.

Por ejemplo:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_function(array1 int[]) RETURNS double) AS $$
...
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

En su invocación, puedes pasar los argumentos directamente:

```sql
SELECT my_function('{1, 2, 3}');
```

...o puedes crear una array a partir de un *select* previo:

```sql
SELECT my_function(array(SELECT id FROM my_table));
```

#### Editado

Si se quiere operar con un *array* usando, por ejemplo, las funciones de agregación de SQL, se puede utilizar como si fuera una tabla utilizando la función `unnest`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION media(array1 int[])
RETURNS numeric AS $$
  SELECT avg(v) FROM unnest(array1) AS g(v)
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: Gracias, funciona, pero a partir desde respuesta me nace otra duda. ¿como sumar los valores del array1 dentro de la function?

Comment: Lo mejor es que uses SQL como en la respuesta de @Emilio-Platzer (añado mi propia versión a esta respuesta). Para hacer lo mismo en pgSQL tendrías que montar un bucle e ir sumando elemento por elemento. Si buscas más flexibilidad, puedes usar otro lenguaje como PL/Python para realizar estos cálculos.

Comment: Estimado funciono a la perfección, muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 2):

En realidad sí podés pasar un número arbitrario de argumentos sin necesidad de pasar un array [ver manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-VARIADIC-FUNCTIONS)

Internamente funciona como array, pero al pasar los valores como parámetros no es un array:

```
CREATE FUNCTION esta_suma(VARIADIC arr numeric[]) RETURNS numeric AS $$
  SELECT sum($1[i]) FROM generate_subscripts($1, 1) g(i);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT esta_suma(10, -1, 5, 4.4);
esta_suma
--------
  18.4
```

En este ejemplo podés ver también cómo gracias a la función generate_subscripts el array de parámetros se transforma en una tabla a la cual se le puede aplicar la función sum (o cualquier otra función de agregación).